# Simplifying a photo of a maze

Tags: opencv, maze

I am working on a project where I need to take a photograph of a maze similar to
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Lal.jpg) and find a path through it to guide a sphero robot through it (a way to find the beginning of the maze already exists). I have filtered the image such that I get the walls of the maze clear and the result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwq6E.png)

Simple approach would be a BFS on the pixels which works but takes too long to be practical. Another approach that I wish to do is to simplify the maze into cells and then solve it. I have successfully done so for an ideal digital [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5QrR.png) shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVV6d.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bf1d.png) (ideal meaning everything is straight, all walls have the same width etc.).

My question is how do I do something similar with the original filtered photo as the method used for the ideal case used the pixel width of the walls which is not a constant in real case? I am using opencv on python.

Comment: BFS on pixels takes linear time.  It's about as fast as any kind of image processing algorithm would be.  If it does the job for you then you should just do that.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I know it's linear but it actually takes about 5 minutes to finish, making it impractical for use.

Comment: You made a mistake in the implementation.  That should take less than 20 milliseconds if you're working in C++, maybe 40 ms in Java.  Even python is not going to take longer than a second or 2.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Highly possible, I am working with python. I will look into fixing the algorithm later. Thank you for the time reference, I actually thought that was an OK time for python since it is a lot of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you assume a known size grid for the maze? your maze is 10x10.

I'd go with your suggestion of simplifying the image into a schematic. assuming you know the grid size, overlay it and test every wall between a square's corners for presence/absence. take a comfortable subregion (numpy slice) from where a wall could be. test counting the pixels and checking if that's enough for a wall or very few pixels (no wall, at most noise).

if you don't know the size of the grid, you can test that. take the flat picture, sum up each row and each column of the image individually, and check for peaks that represent walls. count the peaks.

your picture is warped. make sure the board is flat. then apply a perspective transform to rectify the maze.

[image: somewhat rectified, also binary and walls as signal]

[image: sum(axis=0)]
[image: sum(axis=1)]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The method would work wonderfully but I think the main problem currently is that the paper I've taken a picture of is not flat (as you've mentioned). In the real scenario I will have a flat surface (wood-made labyrinth) and I also know the grid size so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I can work with the picture you posted so it's good enough. you just have to deal with imperfections. findContours, filter by area (ignore smallest ones), try to approxPolyDP each and see if it's a quad, pick the biggest one, that's your target. rectify with getPerspectiveTransform and warpPerspective.

Comment: oh right it's a maze with entry and exit. I see how that would be a bit more complicated than simply findContours... uh I guess apply convexHull before approxPolyDP to fix that. might require some more messing around though... the contours of the maze aren't "closed".

Comment: a hough transform could be useful. you could hope to find long lines, and you could pick the leftmost, topmost, rightmost, bottommost of the right angle, and then take those as the sides and calculate corners from those incomplete line segments. that presumes entry/exit in a corner. if it's in the middle of a face, you'd get two half-length lines... it is possible to analyze the set of lines and connect them across gaps. involves a bit of vector math to determine if two lines are collinear and how wide the gap is.

Comment: I have successfully done it. I have used the Hough transform to identify the lines that represent the walls and from there I constructed the maze. It works wonderfully, thank you very much for your help.